# Organizing query results from Microsoft sql server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I would like to organize the results I am getting from the following query without having repetitions. I would show you in a second what I mean.

So I have this part of the  query that I currently have

```
select ownername,
       hotel,
CASE 
    WHEN owner = salescashier and drinksales ='pepsi' then 'y'
    else 'n'
END as pepsi,
CASE 
    WHEN owner = salescashier and drinksales ='mountaindew' then 'y'
    else 'n'
END as mountainDew
FROM HotelDrinksOrders

GROUP BY ownername,hotel,totaldrinks,salescashier
```

and this is my table

```
 ownername   hotel    drinksales       salescashier
 ---------   -----    ----------       ------------
 Carlos      hotel1     pepsi           Michael
 Carlos      hotel1    pepsi            Michael
 Carlos      hotel1    pepsi            Michael
 Carlos      hotel1   mountaindew       Michael
 Carlos      hotel1   mountaindew       Michael
 Carlos      hotel2     pepsi           Michael
 Carlos      hotel2   mountaindew       Carlos
 Carlos      hotel2   mountaindew       Michael
 Maria       hotel3   mountaindew       Maria
 Maria       hotel3     pepsi            Maria
 Maria       hotel3     pepsi            Maria
```

The following is what I am getting from my query, I am getting repeated data(hotel) that I don't need

```
    ownername       hotel      pepsi     mountaindew
    -----           ------      -----     -----------
    Carlos           hotel1      N             N
    Carlos           hotel1      N             N
    Carlos           hotel2      N             Y
    Carlos           hotel2      N             N
    Maria            hotel3      N             Y
    Maria           hotel3      Y             N
```

This is the data I want, 
I want to group them by name and hotel, and only have 'Y' if the ownername matches the salescashier

```
    ownername       hotel      pepsi     mountaindew
    -----          ------      -----     -----------
    Carlos         hotel1      N             N
    Carlos         hotel2      N             Y
    Maria          hotel3      Y             Y
```

I heard somewhere I can use pivot operator but I am not sure how that would work on my case. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the unneeded items from the `group by` and use an aggregate. Y sorts later than N so `max` will work correctly.

```
select ownername,
       hotel,
MAX(CASE 
    WHEN ownername = salescashier and drinksales ='pepsi' then 'y'
    else 'n'
END) as pepsi,
MAX(CASE 
    WHEN ownername = salescashier and drinksales ='mountaindew' then 'y'
    else 'n'
END) as mountainDew
FROM HotelDrinksOrders
GROUP BY ownername,hotel
```

Comment: if i group them that way I will get an error 
Something like this column 'salescashier' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the group clause

Answer (score 0):

Add the [DISTINCT](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp) keyword to your SELECT statement.

Comment: This won't return the desired results. It will return two rows for Carlos, hotel2 and Maria, hotel3. They need to be collapsed into one for each.